# Merging Two Data set

Tags: matlab, merge

My question is related to merging two matrices with different spacing on the field 
Both matrices are in (frequency space domain (F-X)) and to illustrate lets consider :
Matrix One (A x B) 
Matrix Two (A x C) 
Where (A = 1500) is the frequency samples (they both share the same frequency samples number).
      (B = 168 ) is the number of Receivers for the first data set (recording stations in the field) with spacing of 12 meters    between B(1) and B(2), 12 meters between B(2) and B(3) and so on
      (C = 196 ) is also the number of Receivers for the second data set (recording stations in the field) with different spacing than B. So C(1) to C(2) is 48 and C(2) to C(3) is 48 and so on.

The total length of receiver line in Matrix One is (168*12) = 2016 m.
The total length of receiver line in Matrix Two is (196*48) = 9408 m.

The line from matrix (one) sits on the middle part of line two. 
Meaning they do over lap in many locations where both are present.(every forth receiver from the shorter line is overlapped by a receiver from the longer line) 
I want to merge them (add them together) in a way where the final result represent the courser spacing (matrix two) added to it matrix A in the location where they overlap.

I hope I made this somehow clear

Comment: can you add a short example to clarify it further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `A` and `B` are your 2 matrices then `merged` would be the merged matrix. I used a size of 196x100 and 168x100 for the matrices just because I was to lazy to use 1500 ;).
`C,D` are integers ranging from 1 to the size of the first dimension.

```
A= randi(100, 168 ,100)+20;
B= randi(10, 196, 100);

C= 1:168;  %ranging from 1 to number of receiver in Matrix 1(A)
D= 1:196;  %ranging from 1 to number of receiver in Matrix 2(B)
C= C*12+4704; %Distance of each receiver to 0 and shifted to the middle of 2nd matrix
D= D*48;      %Distance of each receiver to 0

A= [C', A];  %adding distance as first column to Matrix 1
B= [D', B];  %adding distance as first column to Matrix 2

C= [A;B];  %adding the 2 matrices
C=sortrows(C,1);  %sorting the new matrix 
merged = C(:,2:end); %deleting first column (distance)
```

What I am doing is generating the distance (`C,D`) appending them in column 1 appending the two matrices rowwise and sorting rowwise regarding the distance (new column 1). Then at the end I delete the distance because you didn't ask for it. 
 
Just realized that your matrix is not 168x1500 but 1500x168, just convert it, using (`A=A';`)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to add every 4th value of matrix 1 (I'll call this `A`) into matrix 2 (I'll call this `B`) at some defined position in the middle of 2. So we need to pick every 4th value of `B` and add it to `A` at some point of overlap `p`.

Here's how to select every 4th value of `B` along the 2nd dimension:

```
coarseB = B(:, 4:4:end);
```

Since matrices `A` and `B` are of different sizes, we have to expand the size of `A` with zeros so it can be added to `B`. It will help to know the size of `coarseB` along the 2nd dimension:

```
sizeB = size(B, 2);
coarseB = [zeros(1500, p - 1) coarseB zeros(1500, 168 - (p - 1) - sizeB)];
```

This will concatenate a zero array at the end and the beginning of `coarseB` to expand it to the size of `A` (1500 x 168).

Now `coarseB` can be added to `A`:

```
merged = coarseB + A;
```

Hope this helps!